# Vee Validate 3.x, defining ValidationFlags type

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vee-validate

I am trying to find and use the `ValidationFlags` type in Vee-Validate 3. But I'm unable to import it.

I know the type exists in the [source code here](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/master/src/types.ts#L66). But When I try to import it like:

`import { ValidationObserver, ValidationFlags } from "vee-validate";`

It says that it does not have exported member ValidationFlags, here is some example code for reference of what I am trying to do:

```
<template>
  <ValidationProvider v-slot="validationContext">
    <input v-model="name" :state="isValidState(validationContext)"/>
  </ValidationProvider>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { ValidationObserver } from "vee-validate";

  methods: {
    isValidState({ valid, dirty }: --someTypeHere--) { // I'm getting type warning if I don't use a type here
      return valid;
    }

  }
</script>
```

How can I import the proper type for Validation Flags and use it for my `isValidState` method parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most types are not exported because they are strictly internal and should not be relied upon.

Since typescript is structural-based either of those types could fill in for your purpose:

```js
type Flags = Record<string, boolean>;

// Or

interface Flags {
  [k: string]: boolean;
}
```

Or you can always copy the type and use it in your app.

Comment: Where do I put this?